# How to use Backup .dat?

Tags: wallet

I had a Bitcoin wallet with come coins, backed it up (have the .dat file and a .csv file) but recently had to reinstall my Operating system which sadly wiped all my programs.  Now I have a new wallet but do not know how to access my coins using the .dat...  any hints?

Answer (score 1):

Find where you wallet file is located which will be different depending on which operating system your using. Then replace the new `wallat.dat` file with your old one. If you haven't downloaded the block chain yet, then just start up Bitcoin-qt and once it downloads your coins will be in your wallet. Otherwise you will need to re-scan the blockchain at which point your wallet will have your bitcoins in it.